# Radwindow automatically re-sized when AutoSize="False"

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-window

I have added a Radwindow to my aspx page as below.

< telerik:RadWindow ID="rdWin" runat="server" Behaviors="None" **AutoSize="false"**
            Width="500px" Height="300px" **Top="80px" Left="100px"** Modal="true" OnClientShow="RadWindowAddOthers_Show">

My AutoSize attribute is false. Inside my "RadWindowAddOthers_Show" method i am resetting few textboxes.

I am using ie11 in Ie9 mode.

The above renders as below:

< div class="RadWindow RadWindow_Default rwNormalWindow rwTransparentWindow" id="RadWindowWrapper_ctl00_MainPageContentPlaceHolder_rdWin" style="**top:770px;left: 433px;** width: 500px; height: 300px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 3002; transform: none;" unselectable="on">

The top and left attributes are not as per the given values.

Also in the content template i have a div as follows which encloses all the content:

As an attempt to fix i have modified it to the following to make sure my content height is calculated properly:

< telerik:RadWindow ID="rdWin" runat="server" Behaviors="None" **AutoSize="true"**
            Width="500px" Height="300px" Top="80px" Left="100px" Modal="true" OnClientShow="RadWindowAddOthers_Show" **OnClientAutoSizeEnd="OnClientAutoSizeEnd"**>

```
    function OnClientAutoSizeEnd(sender) {
        if ($telerik.isIE9) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                sender.set_height(sender.get_height());
            }, 0);
        }
    }
```

I see that the radwindow is still positioned wrongly(i mean the top and left attributes are wrong). Can anyone suggest a fix to this issue?

Comment: Do you have a radwindowmanager on the page?

Answer (score 1):

By Default, the CenterIfModal property is true for the Telerik RadWindow.

> In order to get a custom position for a modal Radwindow the
>   **CenterIfModal** property must be used.

So just set the CenterIfModal = "false"

[Positioning a Modal RadWindow](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/window/troubleshooting/positioning-a-modal-radwindow)

Comment: I have added centerIfModal property the left is getting set correctly but i see that the top is still not working well.it still sets a random value every time. I have not added any radwindow manager

Comment: after setting the CENTERIFMODAL the html that is rendered is as below

<div class="RadWindow RadWindow_Default rwNormalWindow rwTransparentWindow" id="RadWindowWrapper_ctl00_MainPageContentPlaceHolder_addNewEntity_rdWinAddOthers" style="left: 100px; top: 663px; width: 500px; height: 300px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 3002; transform: none;" unselectable="on">.

the top is still not what i want.